# QR code on a specific labeling? US 8,261,972

Tags: us8261972, qr-code, packaging

I am looking at Patent US 8,261,972, and I am trying to figure out what exactly makes this worthy of a patent. It seems to be asserting a claim that it has a novel invention by putting a QR code on a package. The patent talks about the type of packaging, the purpose, etc...but it seems to just be printing a QR code to link to a webpage on a phone? Does making a claim for specific purpose of packaging and barcoding make it patentable, could I then patent a QR code on the packaging of another product? If so, would the patent holder of the mentioned patent be able to make a claim against me or would my patent somehow be unique? It would seem the specific use case is not worthy of a patent on its own. What exactly makes this novel and patentable?

> Claim 1.
>
> A cross promotional product, product sample, container, or packaging comprising a cross promotional, scan-able uniform resource locator (URL)-internet directing two dimensional code linking to a website or web page including cross promotional information about: (i) one or more cross promotional products or services; or (ii) one or more cross-promotional products or materials related to said one or more cross promotional products or services, said cross promotional product, product sample, container, or packaging comprising:
>
> (a) said cross promotional scan-able URL internet directing two dimensional code associated with a substrate having one or more surfaces, said URL directing two dimensional code linked to a website or webpage address including cross promotional information about cross-promotional products or services, said scan-able two dimensional code provided with, labeled on, printed on, lasered on, affixed to, molded in, or embossed on at least one surface of said substrate; and
>
> (b) one or more of said cross promotional products, cross promotional product samples, cross promotional containers, or cross promotional packaging provided with said substrate, said URL internet directed two-dimensional code provided in a removable or non-removable printed area, sheet, wipe, vial, pouch, packet, patch, container, or pad associated with, or affixed to, at least a portion of a surface of the substrate;
>
> wherein said cross promotional products, cross promotional product samples, cross promotional containers, or cross promotional packaging are provided with one product or service selected from the group consisting of a first product and information material about a first service,
>
> wherein the cross-promotional product or service is not the same particular product or service as said first product or said first service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking quickly at the file history in USPTO public PAIR the QR code linking to a cross promotion of a product distinct from the product the QR code is on seems important to the claims. It **is** a particular way to use a QR code on a product. To infringe this patent a system would need to have everything that is specified in a claim.

I'm sure there are many other particular ways to use a QR code to make something out of the ordinary. A system, for example, with a QR code painted on a curb that one used with a smart phone to pay for an hour of parking in that spot would be "a QR code that linked to a URL" but as total a system might have been unique and patentable at some point in time.

Also, novel does not mean earth-shattering it means new. To patent something it must be new, not obvious and useful.

Comment: So to infringe this patent it would have to be a QR code, on a package, linking to a specific type of information. So, almost the same exact thing but linking to customer reviews would be sufficient to make it different and potentially itself patentable?

Comment: It is pretty specific about the linked information being cross-promotional.

Comment: Story
Tagline
2d artist Inventor of original art image of the famous QR 2d code
Introduction
Inventor and  original artist of the famous 2d barcode image art    I'M THE ORGINAL ARTIST OF THE QR BARCODE IMAGE ART FIRST EVER PAINT SPRAY ON WINDOWS FRANKTEJON WINDOWS offline FIRST EVER ART BLACK AND WHITE 2 DIMENSIONAL 4 CORNER ROUNDED RECTANGLE GALLERY QUICK ACCESS MICROSOFT PARTNERS  WINDOWS WEBSITE LOGO PROJECT